# Items shifting when page is full?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this site in which there will be multiple items. All of them will be the same width and height, and I'd like to be able to add as many as possible. The problem I'm having is that now if I have too many, instead of shifting to the next row it widens the page. [image: http://i.imgur.com/xxXYSxf.png]

I have tried setting a max width by putting all the divs in a general div and setting that one to 100vw, but that didn't work either. [image: http://i.imgur.com/Qe9IcFP.png]

I'm doing this with HTML & CSS but if JS is required I'm OK with that.

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please. Pictures are OK but we need code.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this following CSS property to your stylesheet:

```
/* to your div container */
.container {
    max-width: 100vw;
    word-break: break-all;
}

/* to your panel items */
.panel {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block;` on your panel elements. That will make the panels go to the next line when the end of the line is reached.

Answer (score 0):

```
display: inline-block
```

should do the trick